# Hyperlink inside asp.net email omitting characters

Tags: asp.net, email, html-email, mailmessage

I have an ASP.Net MVC 3 web application which sends emails. The emails contain hyperlinks which are generated dynamically.

Recently I've had to move the application to another web server provider and since then my website users have had intermittent difficulties with the hyperlinks inside the emails.

For example, take this hyperlink embedded inside a HTML paragraph tag.

```
string messageBody = "";

messageBody = "<p><a href='http://subsite.test.net/Entry/SelfAdd/" + CBID + "?VerifyCode=" + VerifyCode + "'>http://subsite.test.net/Entry/SelfAdd/" + CBID + "?VerifyCode=" + VerifyCode + "</a></p>";
```

This hyperlink would result in a URL like:

http://subsite.test.net/Entry/SelfAdd/3?VerifyCode=fU5397s7783jsg

However, since I moved the application to the new web server, the hyperlink will display properly in the user email, but when the user clicks on the link, the URL is sometimes missing a dot, for example, the URL could be pointing to:

http://subsitetest.net/Entry/SelfAdd/3?VerifyCode=fU5397s7783jsg

Or

http://subsite.testnet/Entry/SelfAdd/3?VerifyCode=fU5397s7783jsg

When I create a MailMessage object to send the email, I set the IsBodyHtml to true

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.Body = body;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = emailHost;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

I'm currently trying to see if the web hosting company can help solve this issue, but I was wondering if anyone could recommend anything from a coding perspective that I could improve upon to also get rid of this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: from coding perspective, all you have to do is make sure that the url that you are putting in the href of <a> is exactly what you want it to be, plus keep the body as html.

Comment: This is probably not going to help anything but i'd put `http://subsite.test.net/Entry/SelfAdd/" + CBID + "?VerifyCode=" + VerifyCode` into a variable and use that when you create `messageBody`, just to make sure they're the same, no typos. Fwiw...